# Multiple user roles with heavy logic vs multiple tables/collections for different users?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture

So I am building an API (in GraphQL) but that's not the hard part. I'm trying to decide/figure out what method would be best for my data. So I have 4 types of user roles. 70% of a User is the same, regardless of role (firstName, lastName, username, email, password, etc). The other 30% is up in the air. I have different data needs for different users based on their role. I also don't think putting all of that data in the same table/collection would be smart. As a very simple/contrived/not great example:

Say I have a User model with 3 roles. 1. Regular user/member. Manager. Accountant.

Now say I want the Accountant, and only the Account, to have a field: `routingNumber: int` and another field: `accountNumber: int`

All of the other fields are all the same between all User roles/types.

Only the Accountant could/should be able to have access to these pieces of the User table/collection. I know on the client I can only display those fields based on the Users role but I wouldn't want a standard User to ever even be able to have that in a response payload or whatever.

It's not a great example but I couldn't think of a good analogy. (This is not database/language/framework specific. It's a concept and based on the answer(s), I could implement the feature in my stack.)

Answer (score 0):

Create an Account table, have a foreign key to the User table using UserId.

It's a matter of attribute ownership.  The account has a user, the user doesn't have an account.  Think about what happens when the accountant gets fired...  You don't get a new account, you get a new accountant.